# Turn off cell standby?

Tags: battery, cellular-radio

I have a Droid Charge, but I live overseas and it's not an international phone so I can only use it for wifi. It is constantly searching for a signal that doesn't exist and it's eating my battery up! Is there a way to turn off the cell signal while keeping the wifi on?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for the Droid Charge in special, but on many phones you can turn off the radio separatly. And even if that doesn't work, in your case it should be fine to simply enter airplane mode, and then activate WiFi again (plus Bluetooth, when needed) -- which eventually has the very same effect.

I remember having used [Dazzle Configurable Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hermit.dazzle) for this on my old HTC Wildfire (to turn off radio separatly), and it worked like a charm. On my Motorola Milestone 2, however, I was not given that choice -- but could use the work-around described.

Comment: Most Android devices I've owned don't allow Bluetooth in Airplane Mode. (That's a LG Optimus V, a Motorola Triumph, and a LG Nexus 4.)

Comment: Admitted, I rarely use BT -- but that's new to me. Will check with my LG P880 and Motorola Milestone 2 to verify -- it definitly works with my tablets (Android 4.1.1).

Comment: I meanwhile tried: I can enable BT while in airplane mode, on all devices I checked (including a Motorola Milestone 2 running CM7.2 and a LG P880 with stock ROM). Strange that you can't...

Comment: Just tested my Nexus 4 and it worked. I swear it wouldn't let me do that before. I definitely had to tweak a setting on one of the older phones to make BT work with Airplane Mode on.

Comment: The trick to turn on airplane mode and then switch back on wifi works but if I go in the battery settings, the cell standby still shows up with 41% of battery usage.

Comment: [Toggle Cell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdcollins2002.togglemobileradio&hl=en) worked for me. When turned on, the Cell standby goes down to 20%.

Comment: @GuillaumeBois sounds interesting, but not always desireable: that app switches off the cell antenna when connected to configured WiFi networks. That means, you can no longer receive or make calls, and no longer receive or send text messages until you leave the WiFi. Heavy trade IMHO – unless you're using a solution that does VoIP anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Set airplane mode.

Under phone setting, enable airplane mode. When this happens your phone's WiFi will turn off, but you can activate WiFi again.

Airplane mode ONLY disables your phones radio. It usually turns off other communication features such as WiFi and Bluetooth but these can be turned on again.

There is also a [detailed article](http://portables.about.com/od/otherdevices/a/Android-Travel-Tutorial-Using-Wi-Fi-Only-With-3g-4g-Off.htm) on using an Android phone as a WiFi only device (no cellar connection).